# My function doesn't calculate the means correctly for all the rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, mean

I used this script to scrape some data:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import random

root_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g186338-d215539-Reviews-or'
urls = [ '{root}{i}-OYO_Apollo_Hotel_Bayswater-London_England.html#REVIEWS'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in range(5,440,5) ]

comms = []
notes = []
#datestostay = []
dates = []

for url in urls: 
    results = requests.get(url)

     #time.sleep(20)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='_2wrUUKlw _3hFEdNs8')
    for container in commentary:
        comm  = container.find('q', class_ = 'IRsGHoPm').text.strip()
        comms.append(comm)


        comm1 = str(container.find("div", class_="nf9vGX55").find('span'))
        rat = re.findall(r'\d+', str(comm1))
        rat1 = (str(rat))[2]
        notes.append(rat1)

        datereal = container.find("div", class_= "_2fxQ4TOx").text
        date = datereal[-9:]

        dates.append(date)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes,
    'dates' : dates
    })

data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates']).dt.date
data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates'])
data['dates'] = data.dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

data.to_csv('table4.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

I load the data into my notebook: `df4 = pd.read_csv('datatrip/table4.csv', sep = ';')`

Here's what my database looks like right now:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq1r4.png)

And I calculate some trigram with those functions:

```
def get_top_n_gram(corpus,ngram_range,n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=ngram_range,stop_words = stop_words).fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]

def process(corpus):
    corpus = pd.DataFrame(corpus, columns= ['Text', 'count']).sort_values('count', ascending = False)
    return corpus

trigramlow = get_top_n_gram(df4['comms_clean'], (3,3), 50)
trigramlow = process(trigramlow)
```

And here's the result (I only give some rows, not the entire dataframe):

[trigram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqaci.png)

And so, here's my problem, when I used this function:

```
means = []
for i in range(0,50):
    trigrambase = df4[df4['comms_clean'].str.contains(trigramlow.Text[i],regex=False, case=False, na=False)]
    
    mean = round(trigrambase['notes'].mean(), 2)
    
    means.append(mean)
    
trigramlow['means'] = means
```

it give me this (I only give some rows, not the entire dataframe):

[means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t59T.png)

I don't understand why but some means are not correctly calculated..

Like this:

```
df20 = df4[df4['comms_clean'].str.contains('queensway bayswater tube',regex=False, case=False, na=False)]

print(round(df20['notes'].mean(),2))
# 2.0
```

With the function, I obtained `1.0`.

It seems that most of the means are calculated correctly though:

```
df20 = df4[df4['comms_clean'].str.contains('worst hotel ever',regex=False, case=False, na=False)]

print(round(df20['notes'].mean(),2))
# 1.0

df20 = df4[df4['comms_clean'].str.contains('hotel ever stayed',regex=False, case=False, na=False)]

print(round(df20['notes'].mean(),2))
# 1.11
```

I cannot figure out where is the problem?

Comment: can you minimize this question to the relevant parts only?

Comment: Yeah I can, but when I does, someone tell me than there haven't enough informations..

Comment: thats why you should do your best to fit the right amount of information to get an answer... not too much not to less... just what can cause the errors

Comment: I will try to do my best again so :)

Comment: It will help you to read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. You should post the ***minimal*** amount of code that of course still produces your errors/problems

Comment: Thank you a lot, sorry for the hassle..

Comment: You should add `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer` . Where is *stop_words*?

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with the mean values you obtained. Could you give an example of a mean value that was not correctly computed? What is the value that Python gives and the value if you do it by hand?

Comment: I already did at the end of my post. With the trigram `queensway bayswater tube`. .

Comment: And for stop_word, its in my pre propressing function. I removed her from my post because apparently he was too long

Comment: `stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))` 
`tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')`

`lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()`

Comment: And I already have `CountVectorizer`. It's in my function `get_top_n_gram`